# AIX diff -b broken?

Tags: diff, aix, carriage-return

I'm trying to compare files ignoring carriage returns - which diff -b on any other unix performs admirably. But on this AIX 5.3 box:

```
    tst1:tst2$ od -c testfile
0000000    t   h   i   s  \r  \n   f   i   l   e  \r  \n   h   a   s  \r
0000020   \n   c   a   r   r   i   a   g   e  \r  \n   r   e   t   u   r
0000040    n   s  \r  \n
0000044
tst1:tst2$ od -c testfile_nocr
0000000    t   h   i   s  \n   f   i   l   e  \n   h   a   s  \n   c   a
0000020    r   r   i   a   g   e  \n   r   e   t   u   r   n   s  \n
0000037
tst1:tst2$ diff -b testfile testfile_nocr
1,5c1,5
< this
< file
< has
< carriage
< returns
---
> this
> file
> has
> carriage
> returns
tst1:tst2$
```

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIX 5.3 diff does not appear to consider `\r` as white space. See the following transcript:

```
/home/pax: od -c file1
0000000    h   e   l   l   o  \n   t   h   e   r   e  \n
0000014

/home/pax: od -c file2
0000000    h   e   l   l   o  \r  \n   t   h   e   r   e  \r \n
0000016

/home/pax: od -c file3
0000000    h   e   l   l   o      \n   t   h   e   r   e     \n
0000016

/home/pax: od -c file4
0000000    h   e   l   l   o  \t  \n   t   h   e   r   e  \t \n
0000016

/home/pax: diff -b file1 file2
1,2c1,2
< hello
< there
---
> hello
> there

/home/pax: diff -b file1 file3
<<No output>>

/home/pax: diff -b file1 file4
<<No output>>
```

The manpage for `diff` is a little obtuse on the matter, stating that `-b` will "cause any amount of white space at the end of the line to be treated as a single newline character ..." but does not actually *define* what it considers to be white space.

Based on the above transcript, I would gather that spaces and tabs are okay but carriage returns are not.

One way to get around this will be to remove the carriage returns yourself with a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# crdiff: diffs two files after changing \r\n to \n in both.
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo 'Usage: crdiff <file> <file2>'
    return 1
fi
perl -pne 's/\r$//' $1 >/tmp/xyzzy_$$_$1
perl -pne 's/\r$//' $2 >/tmp/xyzzy_$$_$2
diff -b /tmp/xyzzy_$$_$1 /tmp/xyzzy_$$_$2
rc=$?
rm -f /tmp/xyzzy_$$_$1 /tmp/xyzzy_$$_$2
return $rc
```

Alternatively, you could compile the GNU `diff` utility on your box and insert it into the path before `/usr/bin` - it appears to have no trouble with `\r` as white space. In fact, we do exactly that on our AIX4 boxes since `diff` there doesn't even *pretend* to support the `-b` option.

Comment: Seems a bit heavy for something that could be done with `tr -d '\r'`... :)

Comment: @sarnold: yes, there are probably a dozen other ways to do it, my code was more of a sample. BTW, I think there's a tiny difference in that the `tr` will remove _all_ CRs rather than just those at the end of the line but, by all means, use the simplest tool that does the job.

Comment: Heh, I've never seen a CR anywhere else so the thought never crossed my mind. :D

Comment: OK, points for noting that AIX 4 is even more broken, so it's heading in the right direction? I'll also note that [:space:] character class (e.g. in tr) **does** include carriage returns, so AIX 5.3 is nothing if not consistent. Hey, if I was serious instead of just trolling I'd raise a bug. Anybody got knowledge of AIX 6 that would indicated my bug was already written?

Comment: @tryingToBeClever, we have AIX6 boxes at work, I'll give it a shot tomorrow.